# How to implement trigger-like mechanism?

Tags: django, django-models

I am designing an online game in which players can work for x hours. When the working request comes I populate `work_end` (datetime) and `work_hours` fields of my `player` model.

But what would be the best way to detect when the work finishes? I can add a `working` field to my model and check `if player.working AND datetime.now() > player.work_end` but then again where should I call this, after each request? I feel like it is an overkill.

What is the standart way of doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no other answers, I will explain how I accomplished it. I called the method I mentioned after each request (which updates the user to current time) But I'm happy with the way I have done it.

I created a middleware called `UpdatePlayerMiddleware` to my player app and in settings.py I embedded it with other middlewares.

```
class UpdatePlayerMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.user.get_profile().update_player()
        return None
```

Although performance-wise it is not a very clever solution, this is very easy to implement, and it works like a charm currently. Feel free to propose other answers.